Как написать запрос из 3 таблиц с 3 Join, где из 1 join берем условие, а из 2 join нужно вывести необходимое поле
проблема вывода, не получается исправить. Individuals - хранят имена. На вход приходит имя founder(в этой таблице только id individuals).
В ответ нужно получить имя director (в таблице только id individuals),
по моему коду в ответ вставляется имя founder.
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.inn) c.id, c.inn, c.full_name, c.address, i2.director
FROM (SELECT i.id AS id, i.full_name AS director
      FROM individuals AS i WHERE i.search_vector @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'мария')) AS i2
         LEFT JOIN directors AS d ON d.individual_id =i2.id
   JOIN founders AS f ON f.individual_id = i2.id
    JOIN companies c ON c.id = f.company_id
ORDER BY c.inn, c.reg_date DESC, c.created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Помогите, пожалуйста

Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? №5 и №3
